# Is there a way to consistently create objects in python?

Tags: python, class, object

I'm trying to make a game with enemies that spawn consistently. I've done something like this in the past but used the `exec("enemy%s = Enemy()" % x)` command to consistently create instances of a class. I was wondering if there are any more effective ways to do this. Please link me to a duplicate if there are any as I couldn't find any.

I've tried

```py
virus = {virus0 : Virus()}
for x in range(1, 11):
    virus.append((virus : Virus()) % x)
```

but this returned invalid syntax. I don't know how to correctly do this with a dictionary nor list.

Comment: What do you mean? What does `exec` have to do with anything? It's not clear to me exactly what you are asking.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I used the command `exec("enemy%s = Enemy()" % number)` I was just wondering if there was a more effective way to do this.

Comment: Arrays, obviously.

Comment: @AlphaZetta **never do that**. Don't dynamically create variables. Instead, use a *container* like a `list` or a `dict`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Can you please add an answer and explain a bit more?

Comment: see the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I've looked at the post up and down, tested code out but I still don't know any idea how to do this. It just isn't working.

Comment: @AlphaZetta that isn't an adequate problem statement. Please edit the question with what you've tried and exactly what "doesn't work"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `x` at all; the list indices *are* the labels.

```
viruses = [Virus() for _ in range(10)]
```

or in longer form

```
viruses = []
for _ in range(10):
    viruses.append(Virus())
```

Now instead of `virus0`, `virus1`, etc, you use `viruses[0]`, `viruses[1]`, etc.